# How to use C++ module :private fragment with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr, c++-modules

I'm experimenting with C++20 to better understand how they work in practice. I learned about the `module :private` fragment that can be used to separate the interface from the implementation, while keeping both in the same file. That seems to work for standard functions, but not for template functions.

I have the following files:

```cpp
// File "main.cpp"

#include <iostream>

import mymodule;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "greeting(): " << mymodule::greetings() << std::endl;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    std::cout << "add(x, y): " << mymodule::add(x, y) << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
// File "mymodule.ixx"

module;

#include <string>

// declare interface
export module mymodule;

export namespace mymodule {
    template<typename T>
    T add(T x, T y);

    std::string greetings();
}

// implement interface
module :private;

std::string mymodule::greetings() {
    return "hello";
}

template<typename T>
T mymodule::add(T x, T y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

And get a compiler warning and a linker error (using Visual Studio 2022, MSVC):

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: PlayingWithModules, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>mymodule.ixx
1>Compiling...
1>mymodule.ixx
1>C:\Users\Sam\Development\Cpp\Sandbox\PlayingWithModules\mymodule.ixx(29,13): warning C5226: 'mymodule::add': exported template defined in private module fragment has no reachable instantiation
1>main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl mymodule::add<int>(int,int)" (??$add@H@mymodule@@YAHHH@Z::<!mymodule>) referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\Sam\Development\Cpp\Sandbox\x64\Debug\PlayingWithModules.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "PlayingWithModules.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My understanding is that `mymodule::greetings()` is fine, but `mymodule::add(x, y)` is not because the function call `mymodule::<int, int>(x, y)` cannot be seen by the compiler, which results in no function `<int, int>` being generated.

---

If I instead implement the template function as part of the interface:

```cpp
module;

#include <string>

// declare interface
export module mymodule;

export namespace mymodule {
    template<typename T>
    T add(T x, T y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    std::string greetings();
}

// implement interface
module :private;

std::string mymodule::greetings() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Then everything compiles and works as expected.

---

Is it possible to use `module :private` with function template, and if yes how? Or should template functions always be implemented as part of the interface? I cannot find details online regarding templates usage in the context of modules, and cannot find references to the compiler warning I get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules do not change the *nature* of C++, merely how you access different components.

It is part of the nature of C++ that, in order for a translation unit to use a template, that translation unit must have access to the *definition* of that template. Modules doesn't change that.

The private module fragment specifically contains things that are *not* part of the interface of the module. That's the whole point of them: to be able to stick something that isn't part of the interface into a module file.

A private module fragment therefore can only contain the stuff that you would put into a traditional .cpp file. Indeed, that's why they exist: so that (for short modules) you can put all the usual .cpp stuff in a single file without affecting what gets generated by the module.

Comment: Thanks @Nicol Bolas, that's exactly the information I needed!

Comment: Just in case someone find this page looking for `constexpr` used with `:private fragment`: the reasoning is the same as for templates, `constexpr` expressions have to be fully available to a compiler when compiling a translation unit, thus have to be define as part of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

###### Is it possible to use `module :private` with a function template, and if yes, how?

YES!, it is possible, but only if you explicitly instantiate your templates for each type that you need.

An explicit instantiation is similar to a declaration of a full template specialization, except *you omit the angle brackets following the keyword `template`* See [Function template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) and [Class template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) at CppReference.

In the following example, I have instantiated function template `add` (from the OP) for both `int` and `double`.

```cpp
// Instantiate `add` for types `int` and `double`.
template
int mymodule::add<int>(int, int);
template
double mymodule::add<double>(double, double);
```

If the types can be deduced, you can omit `<int>` and `<double>` altogether.

```cpp
// A more consise way to instantiate the template.
template
int mymodule::add(int, int);
template
double mymodule::add(double, double);
```

These explicit template instantiations should be placed in the private module fragment, right below the function template definition.

When the module is compiled, instantiations for both `int` and `double` will be generated. When function `main` is compiled, the compiler will make a note that definitions for `add<int>` and `add<double>` are missing, and that the linker needs to find them at link time.

What follows is your original attempt at using the private module fragment. The only thing I have added are the two explicit instantiations.

```cpp
// File "mymodule.ixx"
module;
#include <string>

// declare interface
export module mymodule;

export namespace mymodule
{
    template<typename T>
    T add(T x, T y);

    std::string greetings();
}

// implement interface
module :private;

std::string mymodule::greetings() {
    return "hello";
}

template<typename T>
T mymodule::add(T x, T y) {
    return x + y;
}

// instantiate template for types `int` and `double`
template
int mymodule::add(int, int);
template
double mymodule::add(double, double);
```

Adding a test for type `double` to function `main` gives you this:

```cpp
// File "main.cpp"
#include <iostream>
import mymodule;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "greeting(): " << mymodule::greetings() << std::endl;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    std::cout << "add(x, y): " << mymodule::add(x, y) << std::endl;
    double a = 1.5;
    double b = 0.25;
    std::cout << "add(a, b): " << mymodule::add(a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
greeting(): hello
add(x, y): 3
add(a, b): 1.75
```

###### Explicit instantiation also works with `.hpp` and `.cpp` files

The same program could have been coded without modules.

```cpp
// mymodule.hpp
#ifndef MYMODULE_HPP
#define MYMODULE_HPP
#include <string>
namespace mymodule
{
    template<typename T>
    T add(T x, T y);

    std::string greetings();
}
#endif
```

```cpp
// mymodule.cpp
#include <string>
#include "mymodule.hpp"

std::string mymodule::greetings() {
    return "hello";
}

template<typename T>
T mymodule::add(T x, T y) {
    return x + y;
}

// instantiate template for types `int` and `double`
template
int mymodule::add(int, int);
template
double mymodule::add(double, double);
```

The only change to file `main.cpp` is to delete the import statement, and replace it with an old fashioned include directive:

```cpp
#include "mymodule.hpp"
```